# Why are my fields are out of order when viewing?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type called 'article'.  I create custom fields and drag-n-drop them in the order I want.  My user fills out the fields in the order that I prefer.  User then clicks SAVE.  Now the fields are out of order when this content type 'article' is being viewed.  When user clicks EDIT, then everything is back in order, just not when viewing.  Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reordering the fields for the content type only affects the edit/add form. To change the order of how they display (and other things, such as label display/placement) you need to go to Structure -> Content Types -> [Your content type name] -> Manage Display -> Default.

Comment: Excellent! I did not notice the "manage display" setting. duh! :(

Thank you for your help